# Interactive debug of R packages

Tags: r, unit-testing, testthat

I come up against the following problem when making modifications to a package.

Let's say I make a change to one of the functions in my package and I break it. 
This results in my unittests failing (I'm using testthat). However, if it's not a trivial error and I would like to use RStudio's interactive debugger to fix it, the only way I can seem to do this is to cut and paste the unittest code into the actual .R file where the function that I have broken resides and 'source' that file. It's a very annoying process.

Can anyone suggest a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`unitizer`](https://github.com/brodieG/unitizer)** is a new unit testing package available on CRAN that is designed to streamline this exact type of issue by dropping you into an interactive prompt with the evaluation environment of the failing test.  You can then `debug` the failing function and see why it is failing.

Comment: Looks like a good project. Have upvoted but not accepted yet as don't have time to test right now - not currently writing R code.